# Facebook pixel trackcustom event showing undefined value set by Google Tag manager

Tags: google-tag-manager, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-pixel

I am managing my websites tags using Google Tag Manager. Following I have made in Google Tag manager

```
<script>
fbq('trackCustom', 'MyCustomEvent', { categoryname: '{{ecom_category}}'});
</script>
```

ecom_category is dynamically changing in Google Tag manager and showing correct value but in facebook pixel helper, it is showing categoryname "undefined". I am not getting any clue where and what should I check?

What could be the reason of showing undefined value in facebook pixel helper when it is correctly showing in Google Tag Manager.

Comment: Hello Jass  , did you find any solution to this issue ?

Comment: No I could not find its solution

Comment: I found the solution that there was some issue with the google tag manager ,our agency update the code and it seems to be working fine now